magit: How to suppress Tags section in magit-refs of a single repository
I am using a git-repo that has 800+ tags:

It takes about 15 seconds for the magit-refs buffer to refresh which is too long for me.
I tried (remove-hook 'magit-refs-sections-hook 'magit-insert-tags) as recommended by Magit manual Section 9.2.2 Performance -- Refs Buffer Performance.
It works but it applies to all repos. I only want to suppress tags in this one repo.
And I tried the per-repository config described in Section 9.1 Per Repository Configuration:
.dir-locals.el:
; There are too many tags -- don't display them
((magit-status-mode
  . ((eval . (magit-disable-section-inserter 'magit-insert-tags-header)))))

but it had no effect (I didn't restart emacs).
Is there a way to speed up the refresh of the magit-refs buffer for this repo without affecting the tags list in other repos?

Emacs version: 
GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-05-31 
Magit version:  Magit 20230718.2010 [>= 3.3.0.50-git], Transient 0.4.1, Git 2.45.1, Emacs 28.1, gnu/linux 
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"


Magit does not provide a knob for that, but we can take advantage of the fact that Emacs is a programmable editor, by wrapping the function that inserts the tags for all repositories:
(defvar my-magit-insert-tags-exclude-list
  '("/home/jonas/.config/emacs/lib/magit/"))

(defun my-magit-maybe-insert-tags ()
  (unless (member (magit-toplevel) my-magit-insert-tags-exclude-list)
    (magit-insert-tags)))

(magit-add-section-hook 'magit-refs-sections-hook
                        'my-magit-maybe-insert-tags
                        'magit-insert-tags)
(remove-hook 'magit-refs-sections-hook 'magit-insert-tags)

Alternatively you could use an "around advice", which would avoid having to fiddle with the hook variable.
